# VBA - Check if "Comma" exists in a string or not

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to see if a string has a comma or not.

Lets say I have two usernames "David , Boon" and "David Blind".

I need to write an if loop based on the conditions whether ',' exists in the User name or not. Is there a way to check that ? Something like Contains in .Net

Kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: look at `instr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `InStr` function to check the presence/location of one string within another:

```
Dim myVar As String
myVar = "foo,bar"
If InStr(1, myVar, ",") > 0 Then
  'There was a comma
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's two,

```
if cbool(instr(1, mystring, chr(44))) then
    ...

if cbool(ubound(split(mystring, chr(44)))) then
    ...
```

Comment: But `cbool(ubound(split("", chr(44))))` retuns True

Comment: With `Option Base 0` (the default), no comma will 'split' into one part so the ubound is zero. If there is one or more commas it will split into two or more parts so the ubound will be at least 1. As you have noted, a split on a zero-length string does not work since the ubound is -1.

Comment: but `ubound(split("", chr(44)))` is `-1` which is `true` (with default option base)

Comment: I suppose that could be `if ubound(split(mystring&chr(44), chr(44)))>1 then` but that sort of defeats the purpose.

Comment: I'd avoid the array approach altogether. It's expensive with long strings, or with strings that contain many commas.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following approach in your code...

```
If InStr(Range("A1").Value, ",") Then
    MsgBox "Comma Exists", vbInformation
Else
    MsgBox "No comma exists", vbExclamation
End If
```

Or just have a Function like below...

```
Function CommaExists(ByVal Rng As Range) As Boolean
If InStr(Rng.Value, ",") Then
    CommaExists = True
End If
End Function
```

And call the function in your sub routine like this...

```
Sub Test()
If CommaExists(Range("A1")) Then
    MsgBox "Comma found in the string.", vbInformation
Else
    MsgBox "No Comma found in the string.", vbExclamation
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The first argument of `InStr` is the `Start` position. The function will work if you instead provide the text as the first argument, but it can be misleading when interpreting the code, as it is equivalent to: `VBA.InStr(Start:=Range("A1"), string1:=",")`

Comment: I might have used an optional parameter like `optional delim as string = ","` to provide wider functionality to the UDF.

Comment: And, further to @Jeeped's suggestion, have the UDF accept a `String` instead of a `Range`, and the function is usable in more places. Might also be worth changing the name of the function to `Contains` which better matches similar functions in other languages.

Comment: oooooo! Call it `indexOf`; that'll throw javascript programmers into a fit!

Comment: @Jeeped the question was not to make a universal function. :) There is no end of If and But. :)

Comment: @ThunderFrame If you omit the stat number parameter i.e. pass only two parameter in in the Instr function, the first parameter which was not passed will consider 1 as a start number.

Comment: @sktneer No, the `InStr` function has been misuesd for so long, that the internal treatment is to swap the parameters (and if the Start argument is not a number, then default it to 1). It makes it *seem* like the function is *overloaded*, but it is not.

Comment: Well I have not gone in that depth but I always used it in that way unless start number is mandatory to use. But anyways thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

I think that most readable option (subjective opinion, but worth to mention) here is a [`Like`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251796.aspx) operator:

```
Dim myVar As String

myVar = "foo,bar"

If myVar Like "*,*" Then
    'There was a comma
End If
```

Comment: `Like` is about 50% slower than using `InStr`.